# PersistInt slowing down button response in custom preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

I've created a custom preference that embeds two buttons (here I have subclassed Button as FastButton). The problem is executing the persistInt to store the preference drastically slows down the response of the button.

I had the notion of only executing the persistInt when the preference's lifecycle is ended, but could not find an appropriate method to override (i.e. there is nothing like onPause() for the Preference class).

I was also unsuccessful at trying to use AsyncTask to move the persistInt off of the UI thread.

Any suggestions about how I should go about mitigating the effect of persistInt on my UI response?

```
public final class StepperPreference extends Preference {

public int mCurrentValue = 1;
public int maxValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
public int minValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
private TextView mText;

private FastButton plusButton;
private FastButton minusButton;

public StepperPreference(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public StepperPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    super(context, attrs);
    parseCustomAttributes(attrs);
}

public StepperPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    parseCustomAttributes(attrs);
}

public void setmCurrentValue(int value) {
    if (mCurrentValue != value) {
        mCurrentValue = value;
        persistInt(mCurrentValue);
    }
}

private void parseCustomAttributes(AttributeSet attrs) {

    int maxValueAttrInt=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int minValueAttrInt=Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    if (attrs!=null) {
        TypedArray a=getContext()
                .obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                        R.styleable.StepperPreference,
                        0, 0);

        maxValueAttrInt = a.getInt(R.styleable.StepperPreference_maxValue, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        minValueAttrInt = a.getInt(R.styleable.StepperPreference_minValue, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        a.recycle();
    }

    if (maxValueAttrInt > minValueAttrInt) {
        maxValue = maxValueAttrInt;
        minValue = minValueAttrInt;
    }
}

@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = (View) li.inflate(R.layout.stepper_preference, parent, false);

    mText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    Context context = getContext();

    int localDefaultValue = 0;
    mCurrentValue = getPersistedInt(localDefaultValue);
    mText.setText(Integer.toString(mCurrentValue));


    plusButton = (FastButton) view.findViewById(R.id.plus_button);
    plusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mCurrentValue < maxValue) {
                mCurrentValue++;
                mText.setText(Integer.toString(mCurrentValue));
                persistInt(mCurrentValue);

            }
        }
    });

    minusButton = (FastButton) view.findViewById(R.id.minus_button);
    minusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mCurrentValue > minValue) {
                mCurrentValue--;
                mText.setText(Integer.toString(mCurrentValue));
                persistInt(mCurrentValue);
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
    int localDefaultValue = 0;
    Object result = a.getInt(index, localDefaultValue);
    return result;
}

@Override
protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {
    int localDefaultValue = 0;
    setmCurrentValue(restoreValue ? this.getPersistedInt(localDefaultValue) : (int) defaultValue);
}

}
```

Comment: Hmmm... `CheckBoxPreference` (via the parent `TwoStatePreference` class) calls `persistBoolean()` when the `CheckBox` is checked or unchecked, so your approach should be OK. Try using method tracing to see exactly where you are spending your time.

Comment: If I simply comment out the persistInt() then I see the button response speed up dramatically. This was what led me to believe the persistInt is my bottleneck.

Comment: Oh, I'm not questioning that. The key is: why is `persistInt()` so bad for you, when it doesn't seem like `CheckBoxPreference` is having a bad time with `persistBoolean()`? My hope is that method tracing, seeing what's happening downstream from `persistInt()`, might give you some clues. I haven't implemented what I'll call an "inline preference", like what you're doing -- I have only implemented subclasses of `DialogPreference`, where there are clear points of loading/saving data.

Comment: Your call was spot on (and a good practice in general). This is an inherited codebase and I overlooked a listener that was responding realtime to preference changes. If you cut-paste your comment into an answer I will be happy to mark it so. (still wish there was a method override that signals a preference is going away).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CheckBoxPreference`, via its `TwoStatePreference` superclass, uses `persistBoolean()` for saving the preference value, much as you are using `persistInt()`. I do not perceive significant latency in the processing of the `CheckBox`. This means one of two things:

1. I'm a troglodyte and am incapable of seeing obvious delays in animations and such
2. `CheckBoxPreference` does not exhibit the problems that you are seeing in your `StepperPreference`

<sub>note: these two possibilities are not mutually exclusive</sub>

If we assume #2 to be correct, then there's something else afoot. Method tracing, to see where you are spending time "downstream" from `persistInt()`, may prove useful for determining what is different about `StepperPreference`.

---

From your comment, you had a listener responding to preference changes, and that was what was causing the sluggish response. "Inline" preferences, like `CheckBoxPreference` and `StepperPreference`, will be somewhat more "twitchy" than `DialogPreference` subclasses like `ListPreference`, simply because it takes less work to change the preference state (e.g., one screen tap versus 2+). As a result, listeners need to be cheaper. For example, you might hold off on doing significant work until the user has left the `PreferenceFragment` and so you know that the preference values are likely to be stable for at least a second or so.